# Тестирование во Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, юнит-тесты, jest

имеется REST приложение на Vue. Хочу ко всему этому делу прикрутить тестирование на Jest + Vue-test-utils. С тестированием знаком плохо. Документацию всю доступную изучил, но по тестированию конкретно запросов особо инфы нет.
Проблема слудующая, есть обычная форма входа

```js
import axios from 'axios'

export default {

  name: 'LoginForm',
  data () {
    return {
      answer: null,
      login: '',
      password: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sendForm (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      let data = new FormData()
      data.append('username', this.login)
      data.append('password', this.password)
      axios
        .post(this.$root.baseUrl + this.$apiPath.login, data)
        .then(response => {
          if (response.status === 200) {
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + response.data.accessToken
            this.$router.push({name: 'MainForm'})
          }
        })
        .catch(response => {
          this.answer = response.message
        })
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<template>
  <form>
    <h2>Вход</h2>
    <p class="informer" v-show="answer !== null">Указаны неверные логин\пароль</p>
    <label>
      Логин
      <input type="text" v-model="login">
    </label>
    <label>
      Пароль
      <input type="password" v-model="password">
    </label>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Войти" @click="sendForm">
  </form>
</template>
```

Соотвественно когда вызываю `trigger('click')` приходит ошибка:

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'login' of undefined"

Насколько понял, нужно копать в сторону моков, но какой-то конкретной информации как их использовать в такой ситуации не нашел. Можете подсказать ссылки на доки, которые доступны объяснят или разъяснить конкретно на этом примере как провести тест.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Забыл главное, при тестировании компонент монтируется как отдельная единица, соотвественно $root и $apiPath нужно подсовывать непосредственно в тестах.
2. Чтобы организовать тестирование для API можно использовать moxios

Comment: Дополните свой вопрос, не отвечайте на него, если только это не само-ответ